# Interfacing with LCD in Ben Eater's Video

Tags: design, microprocessor, character-lcd

So in [16:28](https://youtu.be/FY3zTUaykVo?t=986) of the video where Ben Eater hooks up the LCD in his 6502 series, you can see that he interfaces with the LCD by sending the data, setting the RS/RW bits, and then essentially toggling the enable bit on the LCD. I can see why it would be necessary to code the RS bit since there is no way to determine that with hardware, but why not just tie the RW bit to the same RW bit being output by the 6502 microprocessor and tie the enable bit to some logic which guarantees that the LCD is only enabled when the 6522 versatile interface adapter is enabled? Is this just a design choice, or is the way I suggested to implement the same functionality faulty in some way?